# Building libsrtp for asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to make modifications to the `srtp` module used by Asterisk. Linker from Asterisk to `srtp` is via `res_srtp.so` which will use the `srtp libsrtp.1.so` shared object.

```
res_srtp.so --> libsrtp2.so.1
```

When I rebuilt the `srtp` library, sometimes I managed to do it but sometimes it failed. The meaning of failing here is that the existing `srtp` configuration still uses the previous configuration file which I haven't changed. I wonder why this happened, even though I used the same command sequence in building the library. The following is the sequence of commands that I use.

```
make uninstall
make clean
./configure
make
make shared_library
make install
```

note : I change from code A to code B and then change again to code A

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully solved this problem. I did it by removing all the libraries associated with srtp before reinstalling the srtp library from its source.